# Как грамотно работать с базой данных MySQL из PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Сильно ли это критично и как можно исправить? Спасибо.

> данное расширение устарело, начиная с
> версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в
> будущем. Используйте вместо него
> MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. Смотрите также
> инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и
> соответствующий FAQ для получения
> более подробной информации.
> Альтернативы для данной функции:

```
<?php // Конфигурационный файл

    /* Ключ защиты */
    if(!defined('BEZ_KEY')) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit(file_get_contents('./404.html'));
    }

    define('BEZ_DBSERVER','localhost'); // Адрес базы данных
    define('BEZ_DBUSER','root'); // Логин для доступа к базе данных
    define('BEZ_DBPASSWORD',''); // Пароль для доступа к базе данных
    define('BEZ_DATABASE','c1hotel'); // Имя базы данных
    define('BEZ_DBPREFIX','bez_'); // Префикс таблиц

    define('BEZ_ERROR_CONNECT','Не получилось соединится с базой данных'); // На случай ошибки
    define('BEZ_NO_DB_SELECT','Данная база данных отсутствует на сервере'); // На случай ошибки

    define('BEZ_HOST','http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/php'); // Адрес хоста сайта
    define('BEZ_MAIL_AUTOR','Регистрация на http://bezramok-tlt.ru <no-reply@bezramok-tlt.ru>'); // Адрес почты для отправки кода активации

?>
```

и

```
<?php // Подключение к базе данных

 //Ключ защиты
 if(!defined('BEZ_KEY'))
 {
     header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
     exit(file_get_contents('./../404.html'));
 }

 //Соединение с БД MySQL
 $db_connect = mysql_connect( BEZ_DBSERVER, BEZ_DBUSER, BEZ_DBPASSWORD ) or die(BEZ_ERROR_CONNECT);

 define('BEZ_CONNECT', $db_connect);

 mysql_select_db( BEZ_DATABASE, BEZ_CONNECT )or die(BEZ_NO_DB_SELECT);

 //Устанавливаем кодировку UTF8
 mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
 mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
 mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
 mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");

 ?>
```

Comment: > сильно ли это критично

Через пару обновлений сервера можно попрощаться со всем сайтом.

> и как можно исправить?

Перейти на PDO или mysqli. Я же сразу посоветую на этом не останавливаться и подключить в проект какую-нибудь Yii, которая возьмет на себя большинство геморроя.

Comment: Я плохо знаю php. просто разбираю скрипты 
думаю Yii не потяну пока

Answer (score 1):

Расширение mysql признано устаревшим и исключено из PHP 7, версии, которая в ближайшее время станет основной версией PHP (релиз состоялся в конце 2015 года). На сегодняшний момент лучше воспользоваться расширением PDO - наиболее современное расширение PHP для работы с базами данных. Ниже приводятся типичные операции с использованием данного расширения.

Установка соединения с базой данных

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
  }
```

Вывод содержимого таблицы

```
<?php
  require_once("connect.php");

  $query = "SELECT * FROM catalogs";
  $cat = $pdo->query($query);

  try {
    while($catalog = $cat->fetch())
      echo $catalog['name']."<br />";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Использование подготовленных запросов

```
<?php
  require_once("connect.php");

  try {
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM catalogs
              WHERE catalog_id = :catalog_id";
    $cat = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $cat->execute(['catalog_id' => 1]);
    echo $cat->fetch()['name'];
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Добавление данных в таблицу

```
<?php
  require_once("connect.php");

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) exit('Не заполнено поле "Название"');
    if (empty($_POST['content'])) exit('Не заполнено поле "Содержимое"');

    // Добавляем новостное сообщение в таблицу news
    $query = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, :name, NOW())";
    $news = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $news->execute(['name' => $_POST['name']]);

    // Получаем только что сгенерированный идентификатор news_id
    $news_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    $query = "INSERT INTO news_contents
              VALUES (NULL, :content, :news_id)";
    $news = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $news->execute(['content' => $_POST['content'], 'news_id' => $news_id]);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```